# Python: Pulling data from excel Type error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, excel, string, integer, python-2.x

I have been trying to run the script below which pulls a certain cell value from every excel file in a directory and compiles them in a new excel file.When I run the script I get the error Type error: List indices must be integers or slices, not str. I thought I was pulling an integer value from the spreadsheet so at this point I am not sure where the error lies.

```
import os
import xlwt
import xlrd

index = 0

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
Testsheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')
row=input()
col=input()
path= 'U:\SWEModelConstruction\Milk'
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    xlsfiles=[ _ for _ in files if _.endswith('.xls') ]
for xlsfile in xlsfiles:
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root,xlsfile))
    n = len(wb.sheets())
for s in range(n) :
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(s)
    data=sheet.cell(row,col).value
    Testsheet.write(index, 0, data)
index=index+1

workbook.save('Test.xls')
```

Here is what the command window gives me 
[image]

Comment: Which line of the above gives you error?

Comment: I believe it was line 19 however I will include exactly what the command window said in an edit

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 2.7, use `raw_input` and typecast the input to `int`. By default it will be of `str` type

> row = int(raw_input())

Make sure, to handle the scenario if user inputs a `string`, otherwise that will throw a `ValueError`